# Better alternative to call multiple classes

Tags: java

Better alternative

```
switch (num) {
      case NAKED_SINGLE:
        return NakedSingle.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case NAKED_PAIR:
        return NakedPair.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case NAKED_TRIPLE:
        return NakedTriple.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case NAKED_QUAD:
        return NakedQuad.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case HIDDEN_SINGLE:
        return HiddenSingle.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case HIDDEN_PAIR:
        return HiddenPair.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case HIDDEN_TRIPLE:
        return HiddenTriple.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
      case HIDDEN_QUAD:
        return HiddenQuad.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);

// more cases
}
```

Here num is an int and all these classes (by sudoku hint names) have a single getHint method (same signature) which returns a String value.
The proble with this code is that it gets bigger as I add more hint cases.
Is there a better alternative without switch case so that perticular class getHint method gets called according to num value with less lines of code.

Comment: Look into using "interfaces". https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp

Comment: When a class implements an interface, then you know that class has a specific set of methods. In your case, you'd want an interface that requires classes to have the getHint() method. The above link to W3Schools is a really clean example.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen so how to reduce this code by implementing an interface in all these clases

Comment: Please check out Interfaces: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

With Interfaces you will be able to do that. Since you are very new here on StackOverflow I will give you the hint that you should start to learn how to Google. This is a question which you could answer on your own by checking Java Documentation or Tutorials.

Comment: I know about interface but even if I implement an interface with getHint method in each class then how this code will be reduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor could only have given you this exercise if you have previously had a lesson about inheritance and polymorphism. These concepts of Object Oriented Programming are used for solving these kinds of problems.

You have not told us anything about those `NakedQuad` and `HiddenSingle` thingies, but from the way you are using them they appear to be classes. But judging by the capitalization you use, (if we presume you use standard-conforming capitalization,) the `getHint(...)` methods you are invoking on them are `static` methods.

Perhaps this way of doing things made sense while learning the basics, but now with inheritance you have to up your game.

The first thing you have to do is to turn these methods into *instance* methods instead of static.  This is done by removing the `static` keyword. Then, in order to invoke those methods, you are going to need instances.  So, you cannot be invoking `NakedSingle.getHint(...)` anymore, you are going to have to do `NakedSingle nakedSingle = new NakedSingle();` and then `nakedSingle.getHint(...)`.

Once you have done that, everything should still work.

Now, to reduce the amount of code, you have two options:

1. Introduce an `interface Thingie` declaring a `getHint( ... )` method, and make all those thingies implement that interface, (`class NakedSingle implements Thingie`,) each providing its own implementation of that method.
2. Introduce a common base `class Thingie` declaring a `getHint( ... )` abstract method, and make each of those thingies extend that abstract class (`class NakedSingle extends Thingie`) each providing its own implementation of that method.

Then, your code becomes as follows:

```
Thingie thingie;
switch (num) 
{
    case NAKED_SINGLE:
        thingie = nakedSingle;
        break;
    case NAKED_PAIR:
        thingie = nakedPair;
        break;
    case NAKED_TRIPLE: 
        thingie = nakedTriple;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException( "eh?" );
}
thingie.getHint( ... );
```

(Note that I call those things "thingies" because you have not told us what they are. Hopefully, you will use a meaningful name.)

Comment: These thingies are Sudoku Hints

Comment: If they are "hints" then the `getHint()` method should have a different name.  You can't get a hint from a hint, same way you can't get a car from a car or a hat from a hat.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution here is to leverage *polymorphism* and progam to an interface, not an implementation. You have many classes all implement the same interface. Each implementation will do something different, but the method signature is identical. This allows you to swap the implementation, without affecting the callers.

```
interface HintProvider {
  Hint getHint(
      Map<…, …> numberMap,
      Board penBoard,
      Board pencilBoard,
      Board solvedBoard,
      Collection<Hint> hints)
}

class NakedSingle implements HintProvider {
  @Override
  public Hint getHint(
      final Map<…, …> numberMap,
      final Board penBoard,
      final Board pencilBoard,
      final Board solvedBoard,
      final Collection<Hint> hints) {
    // impl …
  }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
final HintProvider hintProvider = getHintProvider(num);
return hintProvider.getHint(numberMap, penBoard, pencilBoard, solvedBoard, hints);
```

`getHintProvider` could be implemented with a switch/case or with a map, e.g.:

```
private static final Map<Integer, HintProvider> HINT_PROVIDERS = Map.ofEntries(
  Map.entry(NAKED_SINGLE, new NakedSingle()),
  Map.entry(…, …),
  …);

private HintProvider getHintProvider(final int num) {
  return Objects.requireNonNull(HINT_PROVIDERS.get(num));
  // or:
  // return HINT_PROVIDERS.getOrDefault(num, NO_HINT_PROVIDER);
}
```

Comment: here again getHintProvider is using same lines of coding with either map or switch case

Comment: is there a way that I somehow put a number to each class and I can call that numbered class by num value with single statement

Comment: @Anu I'm not sure what you are getting at. You need to define the hint providers somewhere. Putting them in a map allows you to get a single instance, and call a method on it. If you need that to be a single statement, go ahead: `getHintProvider(num).getHint(…)` or `HINT_PROVIDERS.getOrDefault(num, NO_HINT_PROVIDER).getHint(…)`.